# A few questions about the notion of 'proper class' in set theory

Tags: reference-request, set-theory

In a previous discussion on this website, Asaf Karagila said something to the effect of:

> Given a model $(V,\in')$ of ZFC, the classes of that model are (by definition) the subsets of $V$ definable in the language of $\in'$, with parameters. We say that $X \subseteq V$ is a proper class iff firstly, $X$ is indeed a class, and secondly, there does not exist $x \in V$ such that $X$ is isomorphic to $x$ in some appropriate sense.

A few questions.

1. What is the appropriate definition of "isomorphic" in this case? Are we just trying to say that $X \subseteq V$ is a proper class iff, aside from being a class, it is also the case that there does **not** exist $x \in V$ such that for all $v \in V$ we have $v \in' x$ iff $v \in X$?
2. Why bother with classes at all? Why not just talk about subsets of $V$?
3. Where can I learn more?

Comment: You know, that's my real name. You don't have to preface it by "user"...

Comment: @AsafKaragila, lol sorry. Fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that you can't find that is that this discussion occurred in the comments somewhere, and if I am not mistaken, not even on your own question.

Let me start with the second and third questions. Why bother with classes? It's simple. We often take $V$ to be the universe, i.e. work internally to $V$. Then the subsets of $V$ are its elements. How boring is that? It defeats the entire purpose of the notion of "a class". Classes correspond to syntactic objects, not to semantic objects. Sets are actual objects of the universe, classes are not (in $\sf ZFC$, anyway).

Where can you learn about that? I don't know. I never heard of anyone who learned these things by reading them from a book. Whoever I talked about this with always learned it from someone, or figured out parts on their own. It's not very difficult once you have established some ground knowledge in set theory (which itself can be a difficult task, though).

Finally, the first question. Suppose that we have a model $(M,E)$ such that $\varnothing^M$ is in fact $\{\varnothing\}$. The set, however, $\{y\in M\mid (M,E)\models y\in\varnothing^M\}$ is in fact empty. To see this problem slightly more clearly, here's a layout of the things:

Every model of $\sf ZFC$ satisfies, internally, $\varnothing=\{x\mid x\in x\}$. In the above scenario, the set $\{y\in M\mid y\mathrel{E}y\}$ is empty *in the universe* whereas $\varnothing^M$ is not.

The appropriate sense of an isomorphism, if so, is in fact the following. Given a definable (with parameters) subcollection $X$ of $M$, it is a set in $M$ if and only if $$\exists x\in M\forall y\in M(y\mathrel{E}x\leftrightarrow y\in X).$$

So there is $x$ which is a set in the sense of $M$, which collects all those elements from $M$. It may has other elements in the sense of the universe, but $M$ doesn't care about them. If the above fails, then $X$ is a proper class.

Comment: I think you have misspoken. The subsets of $V$ aren't precisely elements of $V,$ because some of these subsets may be too large or too complicated. Perhaps you're interpreting "subset of $V$" to mean "element of $V$ that $V$ thinks is a subset of some other element," which is not what I was meaning.

Comment: No. If $V$ is the **universe**. And we work internally to $V$ and everything happens within $V$. Then a sub**set** of $V$ is just a subcollection of $V$ which is a set. Which is to say that it is an element of $V$. We don't always work externally with models of $\sf ZFC$, and even when we do, we don't consider arbitrary subsets of them, and there is still an importance to internal definability.